# Show Yammer embed feed to a user without Yammer account

Tags: yammer

I'm trying to embed company's Yammer feed into a website. The feed should be shown to a user who hasn't got a Yammer account at all - without the login prompt. Could anyone please point me in the right direction or is this even theoretically possible?

edit: Formatted the question better.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at Single Sign On for the embed? Here's a code sample:

```
yam.connect.embedFeed({
    container: '#embedded-feed'
    , feedType: ''
    , feedId: ''
    , config: {
        use_sso: true // this line enables SSO
        , header: true
        , footer: true
        , showOpenGraphPreview: false
    }
});
```

Found at https://developer.yammer.com/connect/
Also take a look at this widget for testing different configuration settings https://www.yammer.com/widget/configure

Comment: Yes I'm aware of the single sign on, but it is does not unfortunately solve my problem. I want a user who hasn't got a Yammer account at all to see the feed without the login prompt. Thanks for your answer anyway.